# Is it possible to match OrientDB index keys against a pattern (LIKE operator)?

Tags: indexing, nosql, orientdb

I'm wondering if it is possible to query [OrientDB indexes](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Indexes) using the SQL LIKE operator?

Let's say I create an index in OrientDB in the following manner:

```
create index packageByName on Package (name) notunique
```

Now I can query this index using the equals (`=`) operator:

```
select from index:packageByName where key equals 'value'
```

This works, but I have to know the exact name to search for. What I'd really like to do is partial matching (the `LIKE` operator):

```
select from index:packageByName where key like 'val%'
```

While the latter command doesn't fail, it doesn't find anything either. Is pattern matching supported at all by OrientDB when querying indexes?

Comment: Did the lucne indexing work for you?

Comment: @Ray I don't even remember. I haven't used OrientDB for some time.

Comment: Try logging into your server http://localhost:2480/studio to see the vertices and indices. Here you'll see how the indices are defined

Answer (score 1):

The one way I've found to get wildcard pattern matching is with LUCENE FULLTEXT indexes.

```
  CREATE INDEX packageByName ON Package (name) FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE
```

Now you can query the index using the Lucene allowed fuzzy and wildcard patterns (http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) :

```
 SELECT * FROM index:packageByName WHERE key lucene "Sappo*"
```

These seem to also work:

```
 SELECT * FROM index:packageByName WHERE key = "Sappo*"
 select * from index:packageByName where key like "Sappo*"
```

There's a lot going on I can't quite grok from the documentation, like this gem: I've found if there is only on index (your LUCENE FULLTEXT) on the property you want you can also make direct queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Package WHERE name LUCENE "Sappo*"
```

I can't seem to make it work if the property (`name` in this case) is in multiple indexes.

No clue why the other types of indexes don't support wildcards (even the non-Lucene FULLTEXT).

Coming from a 20+ yr old mature DB, I'm also having a tough time getting used to not having some magic query analyzer pick the 'best' index behind the scenes, but I'm sure eventually OrientDB will get more polish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your use case, but I do see what you mean about the behavior when querying an index using the `like` operator. The following <strike>query</strike> kludge produces the results I think you're looking for; would it suffice for your intended usage?

```
select from (select from index:packageByName) where key like 'val%'
```

If not, you might want to post to the [OrientDB User Group](http://www.orientechnologies.com/active-user-community/).

Comment: This technically works, but it's probably worse performance than if you just queried the class/cluster without the index.   The sub query returns the entire index set, then the like walks each record